# XML generation Python reading from DB

Tags: python, xml

I have generate an xml, that take a param value from the model.

The result xml should be like this `<read><test><value string/></test></read>`

```
root = etree.Element('read')
node = etree.Element('test')
value = etree.SubElement(node, "value" )
for dict in Listing.objects.values('string'):
    value.text = dict['string']
```

I get like this :`<read><test><value>string</value></test></read>`

How should I add the string to the value tag rather than as a TEXT?

Comment: Your desired result is not a well-formed XML. According to the [w3c rules spec rules for names and tokens](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-NameChar), space cannot be used inside element names See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3481004/1422451).

Comment: The closest sensible XML to the one you want may be `<read><test value="string" /></read>`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as @parfait mentioned, the XML result you want (`<read><test><value string/></test></read>`) is not valid XML.

Using the code you provided, the node `test` doesn't get added to the root node `read`.

## 1. Code to get your current result:

If you want something like this as the result: `<read><test><value>string</value></test></read>` (which you said you don't), then the code for it would be:

```
>>> root = etree.Element('read')
>>> node = etree.SubElement(root, 'test')    # `node` should be a `SubElement` of root
>>> # or create as `Element` and use `root.append(node)` to make it a `SubElement` later
... value = etree.SubElement(node, 'value')
>>> value.text = 'string'  # or populate based on your `Listing.objects`
>>> etree.dump(root)
<read><test><value>string</value></test></read>
```

## 2. "string" as a value (*text*) of "test":

If you want 'string' to be the value of `test` and not as a *node* 'value' under 'test', then you should set 'string' as the `.text` attribute of 'test':

```
>>> root = etree.Element('read')
>>> node = etree.SubElement(root, 'test')
>>> node.text = 'string'
>>> etree.dump(root)
<read><test>string</test></read>
```

## 3. "value" as an *attribute* of "test" with the *value* "string":

The one I *think* you're trying to get:

```
>>> root = etree.Element('read')
>>> node = etree.SubElement(root, 'test')
>>> node.attrib    # the current attributes of the node, nothing, empty dict
{}
>>> node.attrib['value'] = 'string'    # this is how you set an attribute
>>> etree.dump(root)
<read><test value="string" /></read>
```

Btw, in XML *good-ness*, the 2nd option is nicer than the 3rd; but botha/all are valid XML.