# How to add or retain trailing space at the end of XML Element name?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML document. I want to add trailing space in XML element name.

**Original Code**

```
<raw_reason raw_reas_cd="FLR0002" prompt="False" priority="1000" min_time_before_activation="00:00:00" last_edit_comment="" description="">
  <expression><![CDATA[MyContainer.PLC.Machine.State ==50002]]></expression>
  <default_reason reas_grp_desc_1="Filler " reas_grp_desc_2="Filler - Electrical" reas_desc="Aseptic chamber unsterile" last_edit_comment="" />
</raw_reason>
```

**Problem**

The problem that I am facing is that when XML parses element `reas_grp_desc_1="Filler "` it trims the trailing space in the element name.

I have tried using `'reas_grp_desc_1="Filler&#x20"`, `'reas_grp_desc_1="Filler&#xA0"` but it still trims that trailing space.

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: Which parser are you using?

Comment: I am using Wonderware Archestra IDE to import this XML file.

Comment: It is not possible. Check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480887/how-to-include-space-in-xml-tag-element-which-gets-transformed-by-xslt-into-exce

Comment: Thanks. I tried giving space between two strings in the element name, like `<default_reason reas_grp_desc_1="Filler Name" ` and it works fine. The problem only comes with leading and trailing spaces. I just saw from the specs, which says _"Before a match is attempted, all strings of white space in the public identifier must be normalized to single space characters (#x20), and leading and trailing white space must be removed"._